# MongoDB modeling for efficient join

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections.

User

- user_id
- user_pw
- region
- birthday
- category
- score
- created_at
- updated_at

Posts

- post_id
- user_id
- subject
- body
- attachments
- created_at
- updated_at

(User and Posts collection both has 2000000 documents)

In this case, I have to filter some condition to extract `Posts` using `User`.

**Conditions**

1. gte <= score <= lte
2. gte <= birthday <= lte
3. region = 'US'

(every condition's range is different user by user)

So I extract filtered users first.

```
db.users.distinct("user_id", 
    {
      "region": "US", 
      "score": {"$lte": `SOME_VALUE`, "$gte": `SOME_VALUE`}, 
      "birdhay": {"$lte": `SOME_VALUE`, "$gte": `SOME_VALUE`}
    }
)
```

And extract posts via filtered users.

```
db.posts.find({"user_id": {"$in": [FILTERED_USER_LIST]}}).order_by('post_id').limit(10)
```

But as service grow up, posts and users data will increase.

Then the speed will slow down and memory problems will also arise
(Currently, already slow. Above query spend almost 2~3 seconds)

I thought it was wrong from the first modeling stage.

**Question**

1. Is this a general way to perform join in mongodb?
2. Is there any good modeling reference that have to perform via huge collection?
3. Other performance improvement here?

Any suggestion, very appreciate.

Comment: Do you have fields indexed that you wish to search on?

Comment: @Sohan Yes. I already triggered index.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to redesign the schema, since your design of schema for `User` and `Posts` resembles typical normalized tables in RDBMS Databases, such as table User and table Posts related by a foreign key constraint.

MongoDB is a NoSQL Database, so the optimized schema design is to embed the `User` in `Posts` Collection so that you will have the details of User together with the Post. 
Even though we will be having User record/data duplicated in multiple Posts it would be more efficient.

Comment: You mean that, Insert `user` data to `posts` with EmbeddedDocument. Right?

Comment: Yes exactly, by doing that way you can avoid join and your performance would be much better

Comment: You know, there is certain problems I think.

1. Duplicated `User` data(you mentioned)
2. If `User` data changed, have to access `Post` EmbeddedField and change data. (I used bulk operation, so can't guess there is no errors)
3. Related 1, 2. If user has many posts, each user data changed affect too many posts.

I don't know it is better way. Because user data change very periodically.